# Which sorting algorithm is efficient?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, bubble-sort, insertion-sort, selection-sort

Which sorting algorithm work efficient for these two arrays:

- Insertion Sort
- Selection Sort
- Bubble Sort

  ```
   int arr1={16,22,11,62,45,37,62,45,3,17};

   int arr2={3,6,9,12,15,17,20,22,29,35};
  ```

Comment: This looks like an assignment to test your knowledge about material you have been taught. Take your time to try sorting each array, _yourself_, and you will be able to answer the question.

Comment: You need to sort the array separately or merge and sort ?

Comment: Which tool I use for dry run I try on paper but its very large and time taken so which tool or software I use for dry run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little JavaScript snippet that has implementations for the three sorting methods, and which reports on the number of comparisons and number of swaps they perform.

This is done for the two arrays you have provided. You can run it here:

```js
function swap(arr, i, j, stats) {
    if (i === j) return;
    stats.swaps++;
    [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]]
}

function isGreater(arr, i, j, stats) {
    stats.comparisons++;
    return arr[i] > arr[j];
}

function bubbleSort(arr) {
    let stats = { comparisons: 0, swaps: 0 };
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let prevSwaps = stats.swaps;
        for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
            if (isGreater(arr, j, j + 1, stats)) {
                swap(arr, j, j + 1, stats);
            }
        }
        if (prevSwaps === stats.swaps) break;
    }
    return stats;
}

function insertionSort(arr) {
    let stats = { comparisons: 0, swaps: 0 };
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (!isGreater(arr, j, j + 1, stats)) break;
            swap(arr, j, j + 1, stats);
        }
    }
    return stats;
}

function selectionSort(arr) {
    let stats = { comparisons: 0, swaps: 0 };
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let j = i;
        for (let k = i + 1; k < arr.length; k++) {
            if (isGreater(arr, j, k, stats)) j = k;
        }
        swap(arr, i, j, stats);
    }
    return stats;
}

function displaySortingStats(arr) {
    console.log("sorting ", ...arr, ":");
    const stats = {
       insertionSort: insertionSort([...arr]),
       selectionSort: selectionSort([...arr]),
       bubbleSort: bubbleSort([...arr]),
    }
    console.log(stats);
}

displaySortingStats([16,22,11,62,45,37,62,45,3,17]);
displaySortingStats([3,6,9,12,15,17,20,22,29,35]);
```

These are the results:

| Input | Sorting algorithm | #Comparisons | #Swaps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| arr1 | insertion sort | 28 | 21 |
|  | selection sort | 45 | 7 |
|  | bubble sort | 45 | 21 |
| arr2 | insertion sort | 9 | 0 |
|  | selection sort | 45 | 0 |
|  | bubble sort | 9 | 0 |

Depending on what you count, either insertion sort or selection sort is best for `arr1`, and for `arr2` both insertion sort and bubble sort perform equally well.

Comment: Why it show 0 swaps for arr2?

Comment: Because `arr2` is already sorted? Why would you expect any swaps?

Comment: And how I can  easily check it through dry run? I have try on paper but it too long and time taken is any through which I can easily dry run it?

Comment: What do you mean with "dry run"? Didn't you run the snippet?

Comment: Mean check how execute statement one by one and how change array in every iteration

Comment: That is really a new question. But that is what you do with any good debugger: you step through the code with it, and it lets you inspect variables.

Comment: Yes it possible through dry run but I want on written format like in MS word

Comment: So then **output** the array at each step? Surely that cannot be a problem, is it?

Comment: ok
Can provide this code into C++?

Comment: Sorry, can you please show your effort in doing this yourself? If you have a problem in doing that, feel free to ask a new question showing where you get stuck, and I'll be happy to have a look at it. I've already put quite some time in putting this up, now it's your turn ;-)

Comment: If you briefly explain code what functions do then I try it in C++

Comment: The code just implements the algorithms that you can find on Wikipedia. See [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) and [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Read these articles, as they explain how these algorithms work.